# python dash button trigger not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my script to see if the amazon dash button is pressed:

```
from scapy.all import *

def udp_filter(pkt):
  options = pkt[DHCP].options
  for option in options:
    if isinstance(option, tuple):
     if 'requested_addr' in option:
       print('button pressed')
       break

print('Waiting for a button press...')
sniff(prn=udp_filter, store=0, count=0, filter="udp", lfilter=lambda d: d.src == '8c:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

but i got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "short.py", line 12, in <module>
    sniff(prn=udp_filter, store=0, count=0, filter="udp", lfilter=lambda d: d.src == '8c:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 597, in sniff
    r = prn(p)
  File "dash.py", line 4, in udp_filter
    options = pkt[DHCP].options
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 814, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError("Layer [%s] not found" % lname)
IndexError: Layer [DHCP] not found
```

has someone a idea how to fix it and get it working under python3.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error is saying it can't find a DHCP Layer in the packet.  Could you add `if pkt.haslayer(DHCP):` just above `options = pkt[DHCP].options` like this:

`def udp_filter(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(DHCP):
        options = pkt[DHCP].options
        for option in options:
            if isinstance(option, tuple):
            if 'requested_addr' in option:
                print('button pressed')
                break
    else: pass`
That way it will check for DHCP before looking for pkt[DHCP].options.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but now i get:
`Waiting for a button press...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "short.py", line 13, in <module>
    sniff(prn=udp_filter, store=0, count=0, filter="udp", lfilter=lambda d: d.src == '8c:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 597, in sniff
    r = prn(p)
  File "short.py", line 4, in udp_filter
    if pkt.haslayer[DHCP]:
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Sorry.  I meant `if pkt.haslayer(DHCP):`  My bad.